# What is the definition of gluing dg algebras along bimodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, differential-graded-algebras

When I am reading Lunts' [*Categorical Resolution of Singularities*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.4566.pdf), section 3.2, I found the following:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be DG algebras and $N$ is a $A$-$B$-bimodule. Then we obtain a new DG algebra
> $$C=\begin{pmatrix}B&0\\N&A\end{pmatrix}$$

However, I cannot find the definition for this notation. So what is the new DG algebra, as well as its differential? Moreover, what is the motivation of this construction?

Comment: Well, I would guess it's $A \oplus N \oplus B$ with multiplication defined the only way you can: with the multiplications of $A$ and $B$ and the actions of $A$ and $B$ on $N$. (Any products that don't have an obvious definition are zero.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks for your comment! I find the answer and it is quite close to your guess!

Answer (score 1):

I find the DG-category version of the definition of gluing in the section 4 of [*Categorical resolutions of irrational singularities*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6170). If we treat the DG algebra as a DG-category with one object, the construction can be easily applied to DG algebras.